# SQL Server 2008: How to clone an entire Database onto a new server?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm running SQL Server 2008, I want to create an entire copy of my Database, all my tables, views & stored procedures. How do I do that?

Ideally copy to a flat file or something like that then import on my new server.

Comment: Backup/restore, detach/attach, and all the flavors of replcation will do it... or did you only want the "database objects", without the actual data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MSDN: [Backup and Restore database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187048.aspx) ?

With Screenshots: [see here](http://www.eukhost.com/web-hosting/kb/backup-and-restore-ms-sql-server-2008-database/)

Answer (score 0):

Is this a one-time copy operation, or do you want it to be an ongoing replication of transactions to the destination server?

If it's the latter option, you can export and ship the transaction logs, which requires much less bandwidth per unit time than shipping a backup of the database. See [this](http://blog.willbeattie.net/2009/07/log-shipping-in-sql-server-express-2008.html#disqus_thread) for details. I've had great success with this method using SQL Server 2008 R2 Express.

You can still use transaction logs if it's a one-time operation, but it may not be worth the up-front investment in time developing the scripts. In that case, see [How to move databases between computers that are running SQL Server](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314546).